# Latex missread the equation and provides an error

Tags: equations, pdftex, align

I have an equation to be written. The equation I expect to have is this one:

[image: My aim]

```
\begin{align}
M &= \left\{
\begin{array}
\sqrt{1+0.6275 \frac{l^2}{Dt} -0.003375 \frac{l^4}{D^2 t^2}} if \frac{l^2}{Dt} \leq 50 \\
0.032 \frac{l^2}{Dt} +3.293 if \frac{l^2}{Dt} > 50 
\end{array} \right.
```

\end{align}

Instead what I get is this:

[image: My output]

I don't understand why. Also, I receive an error message when I run the code:

```
   missing delimiter (. inserted)
```

even if I inserted on purpose

```
\right. to close it.
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Shouldn't the `\sqrt` be outside of the `array`? I would also use `\text{if}` from the `amsmath` package instead of `if`.

Comment: Not a case of misreading but of misspelling.

Answer (score 5):

You have a big error: you're missing the mandatory argument to `array`.

However, there are better methods to accomplish what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
M =
\begin{dcases}
\sqrt{1+0.6275 \frac{l^2}{Dt} -0.003375 \frac{l^4}{D^2 t^2}} 
  & \text{if } \frac{l^2}{Dt} \leq 50 \\
0.032 \frac{l^2}{Dt} +3.293 & \text{if } \frac{l^2}{Dt} > 50
\end{dcases}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Some advice**

Don't disregard compilation errors: you get several of them with that code. Don't use `align` for single equation displays.

Comment: For the record, there's also `dcases*` (and all the other variants) which puts the second column in text mode, writing ``.. & if $\frac{\ell}{Dt} \leq 50$ \\`` feels more natural to me.

Comment: @Manuel But this wouldn't use display style

Comment: I thought it would work automatically through some `\everymath{\displaystyle}`, but if it doesn't, then your solution is better for this particular case.